# How to remove rows from pandas dataframe that contain combinations of the first two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, matrix-indexing

I am trying to get rid of the rows that contain element combinations of the first two columns in a pandas dataframe, for instance, in the next df:

```
     event1    event2    uccs   ulags
0  327423.0  329243.0  0.1663 -0.6013
1  327423.0  329589.0  0.1911 -0.4730
2  329243.0  327423.0  0.1663  0.6013
3  329243.0  329589.0  0.3101 -0.7502
4  329589.0  327423.0  0.1911  0.4730
5  329589.0  329243.0  0.3101  0.7502
```

rows 0 and 2 present a combination of elements: event1 and event2. That is:

```
0  327423.0  329243.0
2  329243.0  327423.0
```

In general, I need to reduce the matrix or df to 3 rows, removing all duplicates.

I have tried the next without success:

```
 u = df.filter(like='event1').values
 m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(u, axis=1)).duplicated()
```

doing that I get:

```
    event1    event2    uccs   ulags
0  327423.0  329243.0  0.1663 -0.6013
2  329243.0  327423.0  0.1663  0.6013
4  329589.0  327423.0  0.1911  0.4730
```

However as you can see, rows 0 and 2 are duplicated. Any tips about how to do this in pandas or numpy will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you were quite close, you just have to pass your boolean array back to your dataframe for `boolean indexing`:

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.filter(like='event'), axis=1)).duplicated()]

     event1    event2    uccs   ulags
0  327423.0  329243.0  0.1663 -0.6013
1  327423.0  329589.0  0.1911 -0.4730
3  329243.0  329589.0  0.3101 -0.7502
```

Notice the `~` I used which is inverse or the *not* operator:

```
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.filter(like='event'), axis=1)).duplicated()

print(m)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Now inverse:

```
print(~m)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you very much Erfan. This solves my problem. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help. Added a small but important explanation just for your convenience. @echaves

Comment: Nice answer (-:

Comment: Compliment from mr pirsquared, im flattered, thank you sir @piRSquared